# Why use Suspense in React Server Components

Tags: reactjs, next.js, app-router, react-suspense, react-server-components

I feel like there is a gap in my understanding around SSR / SSG and `<Suspense />` in React Server components, in the context of Next.js `/app` router.

Question: why would I ever use `<Suspense />` in a React server component?

Situation: say I have a React server component `/app/page.tsx`:

```
import apiRoute from './constants/apiRoute'
import { DisplayData } from './components/DisplayData'

export default async function Home() {
  const resp = await fetch(apiRoute as string)
  const data = await resp.json()

  return (
    <main>
      <h1>My Site</h1>
      <DisplayData data={data} />
    </main>
  )
}
```

So my understanding is that this function is run on a server (Node.js). The server makes a request to `apiRoute` and then uses the data returned to generate a static HTML document (SSG). This HTML document (static asset) is then served by my application at `/`. ie a client that makes a request to `http://<mydomain.com>/` will download this HTML file. (And then perhaps a `<script />` tag will load a JS script from the Node.js server and hydrate the page/application in a subsequent request.)

Now if instead I did:

```
const resp = await fetch(apiRoute as string, {
  cache: 'no-cache',
})
```

The situation would be identical except that a fresh static HTML file would be created on the Node.js server each and every time a client makes a request to `http://<mydomain.com>/` and that HTML file would be served to the client. ie if the data at `apiRoute` changed between client requests that updated data would be reflected in the static HTML document served to the client. As I understand it this is SSR.

But I often see people online doing stuff like this:

```
import { Suspense } from 'react'

export default async function Home() {
  const resp = await fetch(apiRoute as string)
  const data = await resp.json()

  return (
    <main>
      <h1>My Site</h1>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <DisplayData data={data} />
      </Suspense>
    </main>
  )
}
```

I don't understand why. To me it seems like the whole point is the HTML is created on the server before it is sent to the client and in that static HTML there is content that was populated (via React templating) by the `data` but the asset served and downloaded is now just static HTML (ie pretty much just text).

There should never be a "Loading" state. The client gets the whole static HTML file at once and the data is already in it. I could see why this would make sense in the context of a `'use client'` component that uses JS to fetch data and while that HTTP request cycle is pending completion, it would show a loading state. But I am not understanding what is happening here with `<Suspense />` fallbacks in server components. This `Loading...` state should never be shown. As soon as the client gets the HTML document, it's already got the data because the Node.js server had the data before it could finish creating the file that was to be served to the client; in both the SSR and SSG situations.

What am I missing here? What is the proper role of `<Suspense />` in React server components? What advantages does it provide to me as the developer and to my application? I feel like I haven't found a use case for `<Suspense />` in React server components, am I making my life harder?

Comment: `Suspense` is used as a wrapper around an async component, it's like `await` for an `async` function in JavaScript, however, Nextjs does not _await_ it, instead, it sends everything except this `Suspense` and shows a fallback, during that a process called **streaming** happens, you always stream a server component, not a client component. Client components can't be async

Comment: think of it as follows, When nextjs sees `suspense`,  it sends a `promise` to the browser, during that it shows a fallback, and on the client side the browser _awaits_ it. once the promise is resolved, it shows the actual content. This is called streaming. But please note, suspense it only used around server components, not client components. Because it only makes sense when its wrapping an _async_ function (i,.e an async component -which again can only be server component)

Comment: So when you use `Suspense`, the stuff inside the `Suspense` isn't statically generated. ie it's fetched from the client post hydration and then the data comes in (to the client) in the form of a stream?

Comment: currenthandle. Yes this is true.

Comment: Ok well in the snippet I described the data appears to be fetched (and awaited) before it gets to the `<Suspense />`. 
In the scenario you are describing, would there be no `await fetch` in the `Home` (async server component) and instead the `DisplayData` would be a async server component and the `await`-ing the promise that resolves to `data` would happen in that component?

Comment: If the data is not statically generated in the html served and only fetched post hydration, wouldn't this situation be less advantageous because the client would have to make two requests and there wouldn't be any (dynamic / interesting / non-layout) content on the page until the second request completes?

Comment: No. it's SEO friendly, that's what streaming means, it's not just a regular async/await promise task. this is streaming. it means the request response cycle does not close during streaming, if you look at the browser refresh button it shows `X`, it means the response is not yet completed, it keeps generating and sending HTML in the response but not in one go, it sends them in chunks.

Comment: If that's what you mean then consider my comment above _Yes this is true_ as _No this is wrong._.